# Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache, joomla, proxy, xampp

I would like to host 2 Joomla! websites on separate machines using XAMPP with Apache. I need to make sure it is configured the correct way but I am not sure if I understand how it is to be written in the config files.(on both PC's)

things to be configured as far as I know:

- Host file
- httpd file to allow proxy
- vhost file

I have all the basics set up on the "proxy" to run multiple websites from the one server. However I want to put one of the websites on a separate server on its own and still be able to run multiple sites from the first.

for the sake of example my IP address from the ISP is `12.123.124.12`

the internal addresses for each machine:

- server1: 192.168.1.146
- server2: 192.168.1.114

I know that I can do this from one machine with Virtual Hosts but I would like to accomplish it with two separate machines...

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have `mod_proxy*` enabled (there are multiple proxy modules, so enable all of them for simplicity).

Then copy this into your main configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Where 'ServerName' is the domain of this site.
        ServerName joomla-one.domain.org
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia full
        # LOCAL IP of the backend server (must be the same both places)
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.146:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.146:80/
        # The name of the log (so you can identify traffic)
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_joomla1.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_joomla1.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # Where 'ServerName' is the domain of this site.
        ServerName joomla-two.domain.org
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia full
        # LOCAL IP of the backend server (must be the same both places)
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.114:80/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.114:80/
        # The name of the log (so you can identify traffic)
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_joomla2.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_joomla2.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This actually combines a `VirtualHost` with a backend server via the Apache (reverse) proxy. Please post a comment if it does or does not work; I will try to edit my answer to accommodate your system.